# CodeBloks: Unit test file requires entire address of a file

Tags: c++, file, io, codeblocks

I am using CodeBlocks to write my programs in C++ and I noticed the following. Both my main class and one my Unit Test class are in the same folder (say FolderName). From both of them, I call a method that inputs a file which is in the same folder (FileName.txt). From main I call it like this, and it works fine.

```
 obj.("FileName.txt");
```

From the test file, I need to give the whole address of the file for it to work.

```
 obj.("/home/myName/FolderName/FileName.txt");
```

I know there must be a way of setting the Unit Test file so that it works like the main but I could not figure it out. I am not sure if this is important but I am working on Linux

Comment: I have not idea what unit-testing framework you are using (if any), but writing "./FileName.txt" might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My apologies if you've already figured this out, but I'll answer for anyone else who may be wondering.

`CodeBlocks` creates an executable for your unit test and stores it in `/home/myName/FolderName/bin/unitTest/`. `CodeBlocks` runs this executable when you execute your unit test. Therefore, your pwd is not `/home/myName/FolderName/` but `/home/myName/FolderName/bin/unitTest/`.

You're using gtest, but regardless of which framework you use, there are a few ways to do what you're asking:

The best option is to use the address obj.(`"../../FileName.txt"`)

The other option is to copy `FileName.txt` to `/home/myName/FolderName/bin/unitTest/` (or whatever you named your unit test build option). You can then simply use `"FileName.txt"` in your unit test.

Cheers.

Comment: I figured out the second option, copy FileName.txt to bin/unitTest, but the other option is very helpful too. Thank you!!